# How to get groovy to evaluate ${sth} when stored in string?

Tags: groovy

I'm getting a text which contains `${somethingElse}` inside, but it's just a normal String.

I've got a class:

```
class Whatever {

    def somethingElse = 5

    void action(String sth) {
        def test = []
        test.testing = sth
        assert test.testing == 5

    }
}
```

Is it possible with groovy?

EDIT:

my scenario is: load xml file, which contains nodes with values pointing to some other values in my application. So let's say I've got `shell.setVariable("current", myClass)`. And now, in my xml I want to be able to put `${current.someField}` as a value.
The trouble is, that the value from xml is a string and I can't evaluate it easily.
I can't predict how these "values" will be created by user, I just give them ability to use few classes.

I cannot convert it when the xml file is loaded, it has to be "on demand", since I use it in specific cases and I want them to be able to use values at that moment in time, and not when xml file is loaded.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, what we did, was used this format in xml:

```
normalText#codeToExecuteOrEvaluate#normalText
```

and used `replace` closure to regexp and `groovyShell.evaluate()` the code.
Insane. It took a lot of time and a lot of memory.

In the end we changed the format to the original one and crated scripts for each string we wanted to be able to evaluate:

```
Script script = shell.parse("\""+stringToParse+"\"")
```

where

```
stringToParse = "Hello world @ ${System.currentTimeMillis()}!!"
```

Then we were able to call script.run() as many times as we wanted and everything performed well.
It actually still does.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is:

```
class Whatever {

  def somethingElse = 5

  void action( String sth ) {
    def result = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine().with {
      createTemplate( sth ).make( this.properties ).toString()
    }
    assert result == "Number 5"
  }
}

// Pass it a String
new Whatever().action( 'Number ${somethingElse}' )
```

Comment: this looks like a lot of overhead! We thought about using shell and just setting bindings, but it looked like an overkill as well.

Comment: Yeah, the other way I can think of is to use `GroovyShell` and pass the `Bindings`...  I guess that way has the advantage that you get more control over the allowed inputs...  `Eval.XXX` won't work, as you don't know the variable you're going to be asked for... :-(